# What does this scene with Meg turning her room's lamp on and off refer to?

Tags: analysis, family-guy

In Season 5 Episode 8 of Family Guy (*Barely Legal*), [there is a scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BepByFDjjls) where Meg turns the lamp in her room on and off while spinning the tag on Brian's collar while somebody sings an aria.

The context of this clip (which is pretty much the plot of the episode) is that Brian took Meg to the prom as a favour, they made out, and Meg became infatuated with Brian ever since. This is one of the things she's done as a result.

To this day, I have no idea what that scene means. It appears to be a ritual of some sort, but I don't know if it's just something made up by the writers or whether it actually refers to something else.

Comment: I found the scene on youtube and added it to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a reference to the movie [Fatal Attraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_Attraction). In that film, Glenn Close's character has a brief affair with Michael Douglas' character and then begins to stalk him, etc. There is a scene where her character, Alex, listens to a song from Madame Butterfly (which is also about a man who has a casual affair with a woman and then dumps her) and switches the light on and off.

Comment: Reading up more on that movie made me realize that that whole episode was an allusion to Fatal Attraction. They even copy the "I won't be ignored" line.

Comment: The trailer shows a short part of the scene: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKAzinIBo8w (from 1:11).